# How long before sending email to ask for update?

Tags: interviewing

I attended an interview about 3 weeks ago, how long should I wait before sending an email to ask if I am still in the running for the job?  The person who interviewed me travels a lot, so that could be the reason for the long wait, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 3):

**Assume you didn't make it if you don't hear back from that.**

If they haven't got back to you after 3 weeks, it's most likely you are not the person for their position.

I understand you want to contact them so you know if you made the cut or not. If you really want to contact them anyway I would at least 2 weeks, since that period had already passed I think you should be fine to contact them now.

Also make sure you are looking at more than 1 position at a time. You don't want to put all your eggs in one basket. So if you have 3 interviews while still waiting for a response from a previous interview you will have a bigger chance of actually getting a job.